# Eureka server doesn't discover service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've just started to learn about microservices via spring cloud and to start with I tried to reproduce basic example from this article https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring. Here is my code:

Eureka server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegistryApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "registration-server");
      SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

resources/registration-server.yml:

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself (unless running
           # multiple discovery servers for redundancy)
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

Sample service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AccountsServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "accounts-server");
      SpringApplication.run(AccountsServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

accounts-service.yml:

```
# Spring properties
spring:
  application:
     name: accounts-service

# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/eureka/

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 2222   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
```

But when I run both apps and go to the localhost:1111 I cannot see my service in the application list:
[image]

Could you tel me please what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After I applied changes the following line appeared:
[image]

Comment: `account-server` != `account-service` so basically your configuration will be ignored.

Comment: Please paste the server logs from both the apps.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of you application (dependencies as well as logs). The blog has code here https://github.com/paulc4/microservices-demo can you spot any differences?

Answer (score 1):

i have a great solution for you and it's simple

follow those steps:

1- Eureka Server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class ServiceRegistryApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

in application.properties specify those params

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=1111

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

2- in Sample Service

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class AccountsServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(AccountsServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

in application.properties specify those params

```
spring.application.name=accounts-service
server.port=2222

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:1111/eureka
```

and don't forget to remove all .yml  properties files.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did all changes you wrote int your answer, but service is still not in the list. The only change is that `DS Replicas` line appeared. (I put screenshot in the comment)

Comment: You need to start the EurekaServer before starting the Services